# Fastest way to calculate multiple one-dimensional R2C FFTs with MKL

Tags: parallel-processing, fft, simd, intel-mkl

I need to calculate multiple very large one-dimensional FFTs of double precision real input data (the number of FFTs being integer multiples of 4) as fast as possible. Hardware would be Intel with coffee-lake or newer (AVX 2 available but not necessarily AVX 512) and the library should be free for commercial use without the requirement to provide source code of the software calling the FFT library. AFAIK FFTW requires the latter, so MKL seems to be the library of choice.
The input data are in an array of n x 4, so without transposing the data I would have to use DFTI_INPUT_STRIDES of 4, which might reduce the performance because SIMD (AVX) would not be usable, right?
With n x 2 arrays I could use C2C transforms and treat every second real data vector as interleaved imaginary data and retrieve the result of both transforms from the combined complex output, but still would have to use an input stride of 2.
Is there a possibility to make the library do four parallel r2C transforms with quadruply interleaved input data?
All 4 doubles (R2C1(i), R2C2(i), R2C3(i), R2C4(i)), which are contigous in memory should fit into an AVX-2 register, so the calculation should be the same as for a single non-SIMD R2C transform but just using the AVX-2 registers in order to compute four transforms at once. 
Or is it possible to make the library do two parallel C2C transforms with doubly interleaved input data? Like treating vector 1 as real data for the first transform, vector 2 as imaginary data for the first transform, vector 3 as real data for the second transform and vector 4 as imaginary data for the second transform?
All 4 doubles (r1, i1, r2 and i2), which are contigous in memory should fit into an AVX-2 register, so the computation should be quite efficient.
Of course, it would be a plus if all available cores would be used to speed up the calculations.
If such transforms are not possible, would it be advisable to just go with the DFTI_INPUT_STRIDES of 4 or would the loss of performance by dealing with non-contigous data be worse than first transposing the array and then doing the FFT without having to use strides?
With respect to very large transforms, we are talking about n being from about 1E6 to 1E8.
If someone can point me to a site with benchmarks comparing multiple one-dimensional FFTs being done on column-major versus row-major arrays, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: One question at a time ... Surgical pointed googleable ... I would just create a working implementation using several different fft libraries and run comparisons

Comment: Why one question at a time if a sufficient solution to one of the questions may solve the task and make the other questions obsolete?

Also I am a very noob regarding linking and using libraries and coding in C in general.
I will consider myself lucky if I manage to get even one implementation running in case someone points me to something that would be promising.
You can be assured that I am googling my bottom off and I have read quite a lot recently, but I think at some point I need some help from people who actually know something about the matter.

Comment: be aware that its an immediate red flag to hear " very large ... FFTs "  ... as the number of samples fed into a FFT call increases so drops the time specificity of the information made available to you in the frequency domain ... if you are interested in mapping a set of frequencies to an understanding of when in time a given frequency happened you want as few samples fed into the FFT as possible .. if the nature of your time series is a varying signal over time ( for example a song or spoken word ) you also want as few samples as possible .. if your signal is unvaried its OK for many samples

Comment: I am aware of the bad time resolution with large FFTs, but I need a high frequency resolution and the signal changes very slowly. 
It seems that utilizing SIMD/AVX gives a huge speed gain when calculating some FFTs in parallel, so I figure it might be good to have a kind of interleaved data structure, if only I knew if there was a library that would benefit from that (and which would also match the constraints from above).